# How do I resolve this ambiguous call error

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I get the following error at compile time. How do I resolve it without having to resort to different function names

```
private double SomeMethodName(SomeClassType value)
{           
    return 0.0;
}
private double SomeMethodName(ADifferentClassType value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return this.SomeMethodName(null);  //<- error
    }
    return this.SomeMethodName(new SomeClassType());  
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The compiler is confused, because `null` matches both overloads. You can explicitly cast `null` to the class that you need to let the compiler know which of the two overloads you are calling:

```
if (value == null)
{
    return this.SomeMethodName((SomeClassType)null);
}
```